# What's a good logic/design of a SQL script to incrementally update a table?

Tags: sql, database, teradata

So there's this table of just about 40,000 rows I am looking to update. Colleague said it's best to incrementally update the table instead of complete delete and load.

So I've tried hashing out the design and logic of a script to do this, but my inexperience is getting to me. I just don't know what's efficient and unneeded to incrementally update a table.

Currently, the warehouse looks like this: data comes from source into a table (let's call this T1) in Teradata. Then it's sent into another table (let's call this T2) in Teradata with some added fields such as timestamp. Lastly, a view is built on that last table for security reasons.

So with that laid out, I was thinking of creating a temp/volatile table with data from T1. This would have all the data up to the time the script is run with new records. Then, go through the entire table seeing if the ID (primary index) already exists in T2, and if not, add it to another temp table. Then somehow combine the second temp table with T2 and override T2 and build a view on top of that.

Does this make any sense?

There's also the possibility of records being updated. So they would already exist in T2, but have updated data in a new version of T1. I think comparing the values of all the columns from T1 to T2 would be highly inefficient, but can't think of another way to do this

Comment: *"Colleague said it's best to incrementally update the table instead of complete delete and load."* Not necessarily. *Can* you replace T1 with data from your source without losing information?

Comment: "incrementally update" is different from "complete delete and load", based on your source data you can't do #2. Otherwise this sounds like a simple "update else insert" strategy, which can easily be implemented using MERGE INTO.

Answer (score 0):

A 40,000 row delete and insert should be pretty painless for any modern database. Ditto for updates.

The real reason for doing and incremental delete/update/insert is so you can log the changes and timestamp rows in the permanent table with the date/time of nsertion and/or last update. The usual technique goes something like this:

1. remove rows from the permanent table that don't exist in the temp table
2. update rows that exist in both tables
3. insert rows that exist in the temp table, but don't exist in the permanent table.

Looking at the [Teradata docs](http://tunweb.teradata.ws/tunstudent/TeradataUserManuals/Teradata_SQL_Quick_Reference.pdf), that would be something like this (no warranties about this being syntactically correct, since I don't have a Teradata instance to play with):

```
delete permanent p
where not exists ( select *
                   from temp t
                   where t.id = p.id
                 )
update p
from permanent p ,
     temp      t
set ...
where t.id = p.id

insert permanent
select ...
from temp t
where not exists ( select *
                   from permanent p
                   where p.id = t.id
                 )
```

One might note that the deletes might get a little hairy if there are dependent foreign key constraints involved.

One might also note that on the update, the where clause might get a tad...complicated if you want to check for actual changes to column values: not much point in updating a row if nothing has changed.

Comment: Thanks. Is #1 basically to find and delete rows that were removed from the source data?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Teradata MERGE command that you might find useful, check this post:

https://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/merge-syntax-simple-version

```
merge into merge_tmp as t using (select 1 as a,'stf' as b,'uuj' as c)  as s
on t.a = s.a
when matched then update set c = s.c
when not matched then insert values (s.a,s.b,s.c);
```

If you need to match on more columns simple put an and in the on statement.

Edit: If you want to use MERGE you might also need to use a delete statement like the one in nicholas' post.